# Using/Converting pigm materials for blender

Tags: texturing, materials

I have found some nice texture materials which are pigm format.  Is it possible to use these in blender without conversion?  If not, how easy would it be to convert them?

Here's an example of one which would be perfect for my current project.

https://www.indigorenderer.com/materials/materials/205

Comment: Out of curiosity is it going to be used for ncars interiors?

Comment: No, I think it would work good on rope nets